# Generating function from a set of binary strings

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, binary

So this question is in my textbook and there's no solution, so I'm seeing if I can get a confirmation?

Q: Let $S$ be the set of all binary strings of length 4, where for each string $a\in S$, the weight $w(a)$ is defined to be the number of times 11 appears in the string. So for example, $w(1101) = 1, w(1111) = 3$

So i know that there is a total of $2^4=16$ configurations. I listed them all out and determined the weight of each of them.

I concluded that 8 configurations had weight 0, 5 had weight 1, 2 had weight 2, and 1 had weight 3.

So would my generating function look like this:

$8 +5x +2x^2 + x^3$ ?

Is there another way to find this? or was listing it out the only option in this case?

Thanks

Comment: generating function for what sequence?

Comment: Brute force is undoubtedly the quickest solution in this case. If you were dealing with substantially longer strings, it would be worthwhile to find general expressions for the number of strings of length $n$ having weight $k$.